# How to prevent data from being loaded multiple times in a row with Redis in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis, ioredis

I understand that running JavaScript in node is single threaded (which is were I'm running the below code), but am worried that the `await func(...)` call in the below call will pause execution while it gets data, causing the next call to come into this method and call the `func(...)` again.

If I was doing this in C# or Java I'd use a lock to make sure that the thread waits before proceeding.  Should I be doing something similar in JavaScript?

```
export async function getCacheData(
  cacheKeyBase: String,
  func: any,
  args: any,
  context: any,
  timeOut: any = IOREDIS_SLOW_TIME_OUT,
) {
  const cacheKey = `${cacheKeyBase}-${JSON.stringify(args)}`;
  const cacheData = REDIS_ENABLED ? await redis.get(cacheKey) : undefined;
  let retData;
  if (cacheData) {
    retData = JSON.parse(cacheData);
  } else {
    retData = await func(args, context);
    await redis.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(retData), 'ex', timeOut);
  }
  return retData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same promise for concurrent requests. On top of that, there is no reason to wait for `redis.set`.

```js
const inProgress = new Map();

export function getCacheData(
  cacheKeyBase: string,
  func: any,
  args: any,
  context: any,
  timeOut: any = IOREDIS_SLOW_TIME_OUT,
) {
  if (!REDIS_ENABLED) return func(args, context);

  const cacheKey = `${cacheKeyBase}-${JSON.stringify(args)}`;
  if (inProgress.has(cacheKey)) return inProgress.get(cacheKey);
  
  const promise = _getCacheData(cacheKey, func, args, context, timeOut).finally(() => inProgress.delete(cacheKey));
  inProgress.set(cacheKey, promise);
  return promise;
}

async function _getCacheData(
  key: string,
  func: any,
  args: any,
  context: any,
  timeOut: any = IOREDIS_SLOW_TIME_OUT
) {
  const cache = await redis.get(key);
  if (cache) return JSON.parse(cache);

  const data = await func(args, context);
  redis.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(data), 'ex', timeOut).catch(err => {
    console.warn(`Error while trying to set cache for ${cacheKey}`, err);
  });
  return data;
}
```